# wrong page link using urlRewritter.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, urlrewriter.net

i am using urlRewritter.Net for url rewritting...which works fine...i have a hyperlink on the page with `navigateurl` `"~/Index.aspx"` but clicking on the link takes me to "http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/ **ViewProfile/** Index.aspx" instead of "http://localhost:2731/CitiZenJourNalism/Index.aspx"

why?? any help  please.....

**web.config code**

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" 
             requirePermission="false" 
             type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
  </configSections>

  <system.web>

    <httpModules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
    </modules>

    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  </system.webServer>

<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/ViewProfile/(.+)" to="~/ViewProfile.aspx?uid=$1" />
    <rewrite url="~/Reports/(.+)/(.+)" to="~/Reports.aspx?cat=$1&amp;id=$2" />


  </rewriter>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got it correctly, you dont need "ViewProfile" string in your configuration. Simply:

```
<rewrite url="~/(.+)" to="~/ViewProfile.aspx?uid=$1" />
```

Does it work this way?

Comment: my prob is that the link to the home page changes when i use rewritting...how can i fix this??